# How to bruteforce a string match effectively?

Tags: performance, rust, brute-force

I have this code that does a brute-force search to find a match for a string:

```
fn main() {
    let strings: Vec<String> = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","K","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"].map(String::from).to_vec();
    for i in strings.iter(){
        for j in strings.iter(){
            for k in strings.iter(){
                for l in strings.iter(){
                    let mut result = format!("{i}{j}{k}{l}");
                    println!("{}",result);
                    if result == "Kaio"{
                        println!("Found it!!");
                        return ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to be doing this? Can I do it dynamically? In this example I use four loops, assuming that the final string has a length of four. But what if there's a dynamically-sized string that I don't know the size of?

Comment: What situation are you in where you know the string you're trying to match to, but need to somehow dynamically construct that string? It sounds like you're trying to crack a password or something similar? Doing it better than brute-force needs some additional constraint on the problem.

Comment: @NathanielFord Its for educational purposes, it's a password cracking simulation.

Comment: Ok, so are you more interested in figuring out how to do this with a dynamically sized string you're matching again, or faster than `O(2^n)`?

Answer (score -1):

The [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate gives a good macro to generate this in `iproduct`.

```rust
use itertools::iproduct;

fn main() {
    let pool: Vec<String> = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".chars().map(String::from).collect();
    let possibilities: Vec<String> = iproduct!(&pool, &pool, &pool, &pool)  // for four-letters
        .map(|(a, b, c, d)| format!("{}{}{}{}", a, b, c, d))
        .collect();

    for password in possibilities {
        if password == "eggs" {
            println!("We found it!");
        }
    }
}
```